# Angular Modal Service unknown provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to get a angular modal form working but I am always getting an unknown provider error.  I think I have included all the necessary files?

Here is my code for calling the service:

```
      function deleteConfirm() {
        var modalOptions = {
          closeButtonText: 'Cancel',
          actionButtonText: 'Delete Supplier',
          headerText: 'Delete ' + supplierName + '?',
          bodyText: 'Are you sure you want to delete this supplier?'
        };

        modalService.showModal({}, modalOptions).then(function(result) {
          if (result === 'ok') {
            alert("ok");
          }
        }, function(error) {
          alert("Error deleting");
        });
      }
```

And here is the code for the service:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  modalService.$inject = '$uibModal';

  angular.module('plunker').factory('modalService', modalService);

  function modalService($uibModal) {

    var injectParams = ['$uibModal'];

    //var modalService = function($uibModal) {

    var modalDefaults = {
      backdrop: true,
      keyboard: true,
      modalFade: true,
      templateUrl: 'modal.html'
    };

    var modalOptions = {
      closeButtonText: 'Close',
      actionButtonText: 'OK',
      headerText: 'Proceed?',
      bodyText: 'Perform this action?'
    };

    this.showModal = function(customModalDefaults, customModalOptions) {
      if (!customModalDefaults) customModalDefaults = {};
      customModalDefaults.backdrop = 'static';
      return this.show(customModalDefaults, customModalOptions);
    };

    this.show = function(customModalDefaults, customModalOptions) {
      //Create temp objects to work with since we're in a singleton service
      var tempModalDefaults = {};
      var tempModalOptions = {};

      //Map angular-ui modal custom defaults to modal defaults defined in this service
      angular.extend(tempModalDefaults, modalDefaults, customModalDefaults);

      //Map modal.html $scope custom properties to defaults defined in this service
      angular.extend(tempModalOptions, modalOptions, customModalOptions);

      if (!tempModalDefaults.controller) {
        tempModalDefaults.controller = function($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
          $scope.modalOptions = tempModalOptions;
          $scope.modalOptions.ok = function(result) {
            $uibModalInstance.close('ok');
          };
          $scope.modalOptions.close = function(result) {
            $uibModalInstance.close('cancel');
          };
        };

        tempModalDefaults.controller.$inject = ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance'];
      }

      return $uibModal.open(tempModalDefaults).result;
    };
  }
}());
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/xNpbI42UJm8acODSOimR

Thanks for any help

Comment: Change `modalService.$inject = '$uibModal'` to `modalService.$inject = ['$uibModal'];` $inject needs to be an array of strings.

Comment: Hi I tried that but still get $uibModalProvider <- $uibModal <- modalService error

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('plunker').factory('modalService', modalService);
modalService.$inject = ['$uibModal'];
```

Try this!

Add to main app.js dependencies ['ui.bootstrap']

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

Comment: Hi no still get the $uibModalProvider <- $uibModal <- modalService error

Comment: Hi  Dmytro thanks for your help so far but I am still getting errors with no modal form working.   could you edit my plunk and try and get it working ?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include "ui.bootstrap" into your app.

Simply bootstrap your app like this to correct the issue :

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ["ui.bootstrap"]);
```

Comment: No I have tried this and it doesn't work, here is a plunk where I have changed to what you said and I still get an error?                                              http://plnkr.co/edit/xNpbI42UJm8acODSOimR

Comment: You get another error because you have other errors probably because you never opened Angular docs.